# Isochronous USB transfer callback has no data

Tags: google-chrome-app

The documentation is straightforward here: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_hardware.html#isochronous_transfers

It says the callback will be done on the findDevice.onEvent callback.  However, the documentation appears to be behind, because the API no longer uses usb.findDevice, instead, it is usb.findDevices.  usb.findDevices does not appear to have an option to define an onEvent.

Here is the current usb.findDevices documentation: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb.html#method-findDevices

Packaged Apps concept is wonderful, but the documentation is very confusing at the moment.  Would love some help.  Thanks

**Updated Question**
My question is, how do I get the data back from the Isochronous connection?

Comment: It says that the call back will be invoked when the transfer is complete, nothing to do with `usb.findDevices`. It also says that it won't contain any response from the device. So, what is your question?

Comment: @BeardFist The Isochronous connection will send data back, and it does through the onEvent that was set at the time of findDevice.  However, findDevice is not part of the API any longer, only findDevices is, and findDevices does not seem to have an onEvent declaration, so I don't know where to receive the data.

Comment: Straight from the docs "Invoked when the transfer has completed. " According to [this](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb.html#method-isochronousTransfer) the callback has a [`TransferResultInfo`](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb.html#type-TransferResultInfo) object that has a data field. Have you checked that?